# How to put an integral in a function in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, math, sympy

So pretty much, I am aiming to achieve a function `f(x)`
My problem is that my function has an integral in it, and I only know how to construct definite integrals, so my **question** is how does one create an indefinite integral in a function (or there may be some other method I am currently unaware of)

My function is defined as :

[image]

(G is gravitational constant, although you can leave G out of your answer for simplicity, I'll add it in my code)
Here is the starting point, but I don't know how to do the integral portion

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    rho = 5*(1/(1+((x**2)/(3**2))))
    function_result = rho * 4 * np.pi * x**2
    return function_result
```

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on something.

**EDIT**-----------------------------------------------------
I made some major progress, but I still have one little error.
Pretty much, I did this:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
rho = p0()*(1/(1+((x**2)/(rc()**2))))* 4 * np.pi * x**2
fooply = integrate(rho,x)

def f(rx):
    function_result = fooply.subs({x:rx})
    return function_result
```

Which works fine when I plug in one number for `f`; however, when I plug in an array (as I need to later), I get the error:

```
    raise SympifyError(a)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

(Here, I did `print(f([3,3,3,3,3]))`). Usually, the function returns an array of values. So if I did `f([3,2])` it should return `[f(3),f(2)]`. Yet, for some reason, it doesn't for my function....

Thanks in advance

Comment: sympy "The integrals module in SymPy implements methods to calculate definite and indefinite integrals of expressions." http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html

Comment: The integrand is a rational expression, so there are standard ways to find the indefinite integral of it. Thus your expression can be simplified fairly easily to remove the integration. I'm sure WolframAlpha could do it, for example, as could sympy. Are you asking about this particular example or about other, similar problems?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm currently installing sympy so hopefully it'll work. Also, I'm asking about similar problems

Comment: It sort of worked... but for some reason now I can't plug in an array for my function.

Comment: (Not that much sympy experience, but:) looks like you did define this function for a scalar x. Now you try to put a vector in. You will need to define your function on a vector (probably a row- or column-matrix in this lib).

Comment: `f(x) = G \cdot\left( 45-\frac{135 \atan(x/3)}{x}\right)`

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
from sympy import *
x, p0, rc = symbols('x p0 rc', real=True, positive=True)
rho = p0*(1/(1+((x**2)/(rc))))* 4 * pi * x**2
fooply = integrate(rho,x)/x

rho, fooply
(4*pi*p0*x**2/(1 + x**2/rc),
4*pi*p0*rc*(-sqrt(rc)*atan(x/sqrt(rc)) + x)/x)

fooply = fooply.subs({p0: 2.0, rc: 3.0})
np_fooply = lambdify(x, fooply, 'numpy')

print(np_fooply(np.array([3,3,3,3,3])))
[ 29.81247362  29.81247362  29.81247362  29.81247362  29.81247362]
```

Answer (score 0):

To plug in an array to a SymPy expression, you need to use `lambdify` to convert it to a NumPy function (`f = lambdify(x, fooply)`). Just using `def` and `subs` as you have done will not work.

Also, in general, when using symbolic computations, it's better to use `sympy.pi` instead of `np.pi`, as the former is symbolic and can simplify. It will automatically be converted to the numeric `pi` by `lambdify`.